# Make the user only able to see documents uploaded by themselves

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Good afternoon all,

I'm in the finishing stages of making a website where users can register and login. After that they can upload documents such as .pdf and .docx and search for those documents. The users data gets stored in my users table which contains following:

```
idUsers int(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,  
uidUsers TINYTEXT NOT NULL,  
emailUsers TINYTEXT NOT NULL,  
pwdUsers LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
```

Then I have a table called "files" where the files that are being uploaded by the user i stored. The table contains following:

```
id int(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
usersId int(11) NOT NULL, - (Foreign key for idUsers in  users table)
name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
title varchar(255) NOT NULL,
forfatter varchar(255) NOT NULL, (forfatter = author) 
size int(11), 
download int(11) (for later use)
```

So when a specific user are logged in and uploads document, the users "id" (primary key in users table) gets passed to "usersId" in my files table.

All of this is working perfectly fine so far.

Then the user are able to use a search function, where the user can search for name, title and author of the document, which also works fine.

I only need to make sure the user only can see the documents, that are being uploaded by themselves. But I can't figure it out. I've tried many different solutions so far.

I've tried a suggestion i saw, where i tried to make my mysqli_query look like this:

```
"
SELECT * 
  FROM files 
 WHERE id 
   AND usersId name LIKE '%$searchingq%' 
    OR title LIKE '%$searchingq%' 
    OR forfatter LIKE '%$searchingq%' 
   AND usersId='.$usersId.'"
```

That wasn't working out well. It felt like the sessions wasn't finding the id of the current $_SESSION.

My search .php looks like this:

```
    $usersId = $_SESSION['userId'];

    $output = '';

    if (isset($_GET['search']) && $_GET['search'] !== ' ') {
        $searchingq = $_GET['search'];

        $q = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM files WHERE `usersId` = {$usersId} AND (`name` LIKE '%{$searchingq}%' OR `title` LIKE '%{$searchingq}%' OR `forfatter` LIKE '%{$searchingq}% )"); 

        $c = mysqli_num_rows($q);

        if($c == 0) {
            $output = '<p>No search results for: "' .$searchingq. '"</p>';
        } else {


            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q)) {
                $name = $row['name'];
                $title = $row['title'];
                $forfatter = $row['forfatter'];
                $download = $row['downloads'];

                $output .=
```

Help is very appreciated!

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Under what circumstances might 'where id' be false?

Comment: You are wrapping the column names in single quotes (') which turns them into strings. Not what you want. Wrap them in backticks (`). \`title\`, not 'title'. Or don't wrap them in anything at all.

Comment: You have `if($c == 0)` but you never set `$c`.

Comment: I can see I haven't include what $c is in this edit. But before the if statements start, i got this one $c = mysqli_num_rows($q);

Comment: @ryantxr I've made another edit so you can see what I mean

Answer (score 0):

When doing code like this, I like to first run the query itself just to get it right.
This type of filtering should be easy because you already have each file associated to a user.

The base query would be like this:

Assuming you are looking for files for user 99.

This is the basic query and is intended only to show how to get the files for a user. This does not go into the code.

```
SELECT * FROM files
WHERE `usersId` = 99
```

This would give you only files that belong to that user. Again, this is only to explain the query, not to go in the code.

Now let's add to the above query to include the search criteria. Assume we are looking for 'foo'

```
SELECT * FROM files
WHERE `usersId` = 99
AND (`name` LIKE '%foo%'
    OR `title` LIKE '%foo%'
    OR `forfatter` LIKE '%foo%' )
```

We now have a query we can use in code. Try this out by running it directly against your database.

This query says to find all the files for that user when **any** of the columns match the search criteria. You can, therefore, write this in PHP something like this:

(Some code has been removed for the sake of brevity)

```
$usersId = $_SESSION['userId']; // the user id of the logged in user.
// code removed
$searchingq = $_GET['search']; // the search string
$q = mysqli_query($conn, "
SELECT * FROM files
WHERE `usersId` = {$usersId}
AND (`name` LIKE '%{$searchingq}%'
    OR `title` LIKE '%{$searchingq}%'
    OR `forfatter` LIKE '%{$searchingq}% )";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q)) {

    // Do output here

}
```

The following is how to do it with prepared statements.
You can learn more about Prepared Statements here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

```
$stmt = $mysqli_prepare($conn, "
    SELECT * FROM files
      WHERE `usersId` = ?
      AND (`name` LIKE '%?%'
        OR `title` LIKE '%?%'
        OR `forfatter` LIKE '%?% )");
 // Replace the ?'s with the actual values.
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "isss", $usersId, $searchingq, $searchingq, $searchingq);

 mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
 $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     // output goes here
 }
```

Comment: So you would make two mysqli_queries? Then I get kinda confused, where I should place those in my document. And since I want to search for the user thats active in the current session, I guess my first sql statement should be like this: "SELECT * FROM files WHERE usersId = '.$usersId.' AND name like '%{$searchingq}%' OR 'title' LIKE '%{$searchingq}%' OR forfatter LIKE '%{$searchingq}%';

Comment: No. I am only including queries to show you how to start with a simple query and add to it in a methodical fashion. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will give it a shot!

Comment: Could you teach the OP how to do it with prepared statements, please? Your solution will not work for names like for example `O'Connor`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. You are correct. I have intentionally kept the code almost the same from the question so he can compare. IMO, this question is more about learning how to write the query than PHP.

Comment: True, but I would still consider this query invalid if it is going to fail for certain inputs. Instead if you want to keep it about SQL query only, you could abstract from PHP altogether and keep only SQL in your answer. Then OP can do research on his own how to execute SQL queries in PHP (see my comment)

Comment: Per your demand, I have added prepared statements to the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't solve the problem for me. So I'm stilling working on it ^^

Comment: @ryantxr It seems like when I'm trying your suggestion, it can't find the documents stored in my files table for some reason. I have made a edit to this post, containing your suggestion. Am I doing anything wrong or what?

Comment: and btw @ryantxr I can't either upvote or downvote answers yet, since I'm still a fairly new user :)

Comment: There is a slight issue with this "LIKE '%{$searchingq}% )". It is missing a closing single quote. Should be "LIKE '%{$searchingq}%' )"

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could try adding `AND usersId=".$userId` to the end of your query.